# Exportar MYSQL a JSON

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Si un script de una base de datos completa la exporto en formato JSON, funcionara para utilizarla directamente en Firebase. he notado que hay errores como acentos y con carácter ñ que se ocupa en Latinoamérica, además escapa los directorios con caracteres /.  es recomendable exportarlo directamente desde phpadmin, o es necesario utilizar otra herramienta, para evitar errores y sobre todo la estructura y sus relaciones.

```
[{
"IdArticulo": "38",
"Barra": "020115",
"NombreArticulo": "Lasag\u00f1a de Carne",
"Estado": "1",
"IdSubCategoria": "4"
}]
```

otro ejemplo es:

```
[{
    "IdArticuloComercio": "9",
    "IdArticulo": "22",
    "IdComercio": "1",
    "Descripcion": "Tortilla ",
    "UM": "UN",
    "Transaccion": "gah11bf9ou7urtfq3d3lu21pc2",
    "Minimo": "2",
    "Maximo": "10",
    "PrecioCosto": "0.05",
    "PrecioVenta": "0.1",
    "Imagen": "\/cafeteria\/app\/images\/productos\/tortillas.jpg",
    "IdUsuarioComercio": "1",
    "Estado": "1"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inevitablemente tendras este resultado. Podria mejorarlo si cambias la codificacion de la base de datos, pero tambien tendrias unos caracteres con el mismo comportamiento. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es

1. Consultar a la base de datos y pedir los datos que quieres exportar
2. Cuando los tengas, con un ciclo foreach recorre los datos y aplicale una funcion para limpiar cada caracter y metes ese registro en un array.
3. Al tener los datos limpios, crea un archivo json con
   file_put_contents('archivos/minuevoArchivo.json', json_encode($myArray));

Y ya te quedaria esa herramienta disponible para cuando quieras hacer algo similar. No tienes que subirla  a un servidor ni nada.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Alvaro Aliaga, me parece muy bien, porque en la BD y PHP no tengo problema, pero quiero cambiar de tecnología una aplicación y la lógica del negocio me funciona de maravilla, pero al migrar a JSON no quiero cambiar su estructura.